# Injecting the Doctrine Entity Manager in services - Bad practice?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Using https://insight.sensiolabs.com to scan / check my code, I get the following warning:

`The Doctrine Entity Manager should not be passed as an argument.`

Why is it such a bad practice to inject the Entity Manager in a service? What is a solution?

Comment: See if it complains about injecting a Doctrine Entity Repository.  Repositories have a somewhat narrower "scope" than managers so, in general, it's better to inject repositories.  Easier to mock and test etc.

Comment: Repositories are no problem, but repo's can't be used to persist entities to the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With respect to the comment that repositories cannot persist entities.

```
class MyRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function persist($entity) { return $this->_em->persist($entity); }
    public function flush  ()        { return $this->_em->flush  (); }
```

I like to make my repositories follow more or less a "standard" repository interface.  So I do:

```
interface NyRepositoryInterface
[
    function save($entity);
    function commit();
}
class MyRepository extends EntityRepository implements MyRepositoryInterface
{
    public function save  ($entity) { return $this->_em->persist($entity); }
    public function commit()        { return $this->_em->flush  (); }
```

This allows me to define and inject non-doctrine repositories.

You might object to having to add these helper functions to every repository.  But I find that a bit of copy/paste is worth it.  Traits might help here as well.

The idea is move away from the whole concept of an entity manager.

Comment: Seems like a great solution, just curious if other developers do this another way.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks. Only a small correction: methods persist and flush are void and don't return anything

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a quite a large project currently and have recently started following the approach with repositories that can mutate data. I don't really understand the motivation behind having to inject EntityManager as a dependency which is as bad as injecting ServiceManager to any class. It is just a bad design that people try to justify. Such operations like persist, remove and flush can be abstracted into sth like AbstractMutableRepository that every other repository can inherit from. So far it has been doing quite well and makes code more readable and easier to unit test!
Show me at least one example of a service that has EM injected and unit test for it looked correctly? To be able to unit test sth that has EM injected is more about testing implementation than anything else. What happens is then you end up having so many mocks set up for it, you cannot really call it a decent unit test! It is a code coverage hitter, nothing more!

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: It actually is :) Read carefully.
Why is it such a bad practice to inject the Entity Manager in a service?
Because EntityManager is similar to ServiceManager in the DB world. It can do everything and you are not supposed to make your classes dependent on the whole world as you cannot really unit test it properly.

Comment: The pattern proposed by the author of Doctrine2 ie inject EntityManager just for getting our repository out of it, it is a bad idea. Why? With Entity manager you can do thing A in a couple of ways. It is a big monster of many responsibilities that is impossible to be stubbed or mocked out in any reasonable way. Therefore we have Repository (pattern) to reduce the scope and make it clear what the dependency is for. Injecting a world to anywhere makes a component less portable, more brittle, harder to unit test and reason about.